# Why two times the callback invoked in CreateServer of http in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

i am trying with following code:

```
const  http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');


var hServer = http.createServer( (req, res) => {
        console.log ("Received Connection..");
        fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, page) {
                res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                res.write(page);
                res.end();

        });
});

hServer.listen(8989);
```

When i connect from browser http://localhost:8989,
I received two times the console print  "Received Connection." Why?

Comment: If you print `req.path`, I m pretty sure you'll see `localhost` and `localhost/favicon`

Comment: I am getting undefined if i print req.path

Comment: Sorry, used to Express. Try `req.url`

Comment: Super It works. I see two request one is '/', and the another one is /favicon. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const  http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');


var hServer = http.createServer( (req, res) => {
        console.log ("Received Connection...");
        console.log('URL: ' + req.url);
        fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, page) {
                res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                res.write(page);
                res.end();

        });
});

hServer.listen(8989);
```

Will print:

```
Received Connection...
URL: /
Received Connection...
URL: /favicon
```

It is because the browser automatically ask for the favicon, the little icon you see in your tabs.
If you fire your request from POSTMan, wget, curl, or other http tools, you'll only see one request.

Answer (score 2):

This can be traced down by logging out `req` using `console.log(req)`.

Looking at the raw request we see that the browser additionally requests /favicon for each request.

```
url: '/',
url: '/favicon.ico',
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel.